# python selenium как использовать proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

как использовать http прокси и https используя FireFox подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
...
proxy = "x.x.x.x:yyyy"

firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется использовать прокси с авторизацией, то сделать это средствами selenium не получится. Так как в selenium нет поддержки работы с алертами просящими пароль. Я написал дополнение для Firefox с помощью которого можно решать как проблему с прокси так и с куки и заголовками.

https://github.com/alexsok-bit/selenium_helper

Возможно использовать дополнение из директории releases, оно уже подписано

Comment: у вас в selenium_helper там есть вот такой код:
proxy = urllib.parse.urlparse("http://username:password@host:port")
proxy = {
    "type": proxy.scheme, что сюда нужно вставить?
    "host": proxy.hostname,
    "port": proxy.port,
    "username": proxy.username,
    "password": proxy.password
}

Comment: прочитай ридми пожалуйста. а вообще в это нужно чтобы распарсить прокси. должно быть не username:password@host:port а `http://proxy_user:proxy_password@proxy_host:proxy_port`. подразумевается что клиенту так будет привычнее.